# What is a good Google Fonts serif typeface for a content website?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, serif

the authors on my website insist we use serif typeface as it identifies our purpose. I've tried two fonts, Playfair Display and Sanchez, but both have visual problems.

I need a very simple, highly readable, and soft on the eyes serif typeface that can be linked from Google Fonts.

This is the website with Sanchez right now, and as you can see, it's not particularly easy on the eyes.

---

[image: A webpage with body text set in the serif typeface 'Sanchez.']

Comment: Yeah, those two would look awkward. Display fonts (like Playfair Display) are intended for large sizes, like headings and signage. Likewise Sanchez is a slab serif and can also be awkward to read in body text. So in your search, you probably want to exclude display and slab serif fonts. There are many good serif fonts for webpages.

Comment: @Abhimanyu: please add a screenshot of what's behind the link. Link rot is a big issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baskerville is one of my favorite serif font. Clear, easy to read, eyes catcher, elegant, ...
Click on [this link](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Libre+Baskerville?authuser=1&query=basker) to get the Google Fonts Baskerville's page.

I hope you will like it as much as the 2.725.477 sites that use this font.

Cheers !

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would say the following are a great bet for content set in serif font:

Lora // https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lora
[image]

Source Serif Pro

Roboto Slab